# How to Select attribute value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have three `div`s with dname attribute's of d1, d2 and d3.

How can I select the value of dname=d2 and display it in a new div?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.attr()` method in jQuery to grab the respective '*attribute value*' of a selected element.
eg.

```
$(this).attr("dname");
```

Also I recommend to change the attribute names from `dname` to `data-dname` doing so shall allow you to use the jQuerys `.data()` method to directly access that value.

```
$(this).data("dname");
```

**Note:-** `.data()` requires jQuery `>= v1.4.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute selector, like so:

```
$("[dname='d2']")
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/z82or2d3/) to show a working example.

Comment: Thank u.. its working